# Give an example of a map $\pi:\Bbb N\to\Bbb N$ with a right inverse but no left inverse and vice versa

Tags: functions

I'm really struggling with this as I can't think of anything that would work one way and not the other

Comment: You should ask your question on the question body and not just on the title.

Comment: Are you aware of the relationships between one-sided inverses, injectivity, and surjectivity?

Comment: @JonasMeyer No I am not

Answer (score 3):

It might help to recall the basic theorem that a function has a left-inverse iff it is injective, and a right-inverse iff it is surjective. If that doesn't sound familiar, then pause to look it up in any introductory text, as it is pretty crucial. [There's a wrinkle which doesn't matter here.]

So your task comes to this: to find a function $f\colon\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ which is surjective but not injective, and to find one which is injective and not surjective.

Answer (score 3):

You want to construct $\pi$ so that there is a map $\rho:\Bbb N\to\Bbb N$ such that $\pi\circ\rho=\mathrm{id}_{\Bbb N}$, but there is no map $\sigma$ such that $\sigma\circ\pi=\mathrm{id}_{\Bbb N}$. In other words, $\rho$ does something that $\pi$ undoes, but $\pi$ does something that can’t be undone. To make sure that $\pi$ does something that can’t be undone by another map, make sure that $\pi$ is not injective: it sends two different natural numbers to the same natural number. To keep things simple, let’s see what we can do with $\pi(0)=\pi(1)=0$. On the other hand, we’d like to keep $\pi$ as nearly one-to-one (injective) as possible, to make it easier for it to be a left inverse to some function. What about just filling in the remaining values in the simplest one-to-one fashion?

$$\pi:\Bbb N\to\Bbb N:n\mapsto\begin{cases}n-1,&\text{if }n>0\\0,&\text{if }n=0\;.\end{cases}$$

(My $\Bbb N$ includes $0$.) Clearly $\pi$’s collapsing of $0$ and $1$ to the same value can’t be undone, so $\pi$ has no left inverse. Does $\pi$ have a right inverse?

Comment: Yes because if you go the other way everything maps 1 to 1

Comment: @user59164: Yes, it is. But can you specify a right inverse, i.e., actually write down the definition of a function that *is* a right inverse? There’s a pretty obvious one ...